# Python3 dictionary filtering, why is one method so faster than another?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two similar length lists `ids`, `descriptions` and both contain strings only.
I have `special_ids` which is also a list, containing a subset of `ids`

I have tried two different approaches

```
# 1
filtered = {k:v for k,v in zip(ids, descriptions) if k in special_ids}

# 2
filtered = {k:v for k,v in zip(ids, descriptions)}
filtered = {k: v for k,v in filtered if k in special_ids}
```

The second one was waaay faster. I'm talking in the minutes where `len(ids)` is 370k~ and `len(special_ids)` is 1.2k~

Why should the second one run so much faster?

*Side note:
In the actual problem, the elements of `ids` are one element lists of encoded strings, so actually I unpack them like `k[0].decode() for k in ids` in each one of the solutions, I don't think that matters though*

Comment: the second one can be probably made even faster by `filtered = dict(zip(ids, descriptions))`

Comment: Can you provide a MCVE? Also specify if python 2 or 3 please

Comment: Are you sure, list `ids` doesn't has any repeated values? If it has repeated values, it will be overwritten by `filtered = {k:v for k,v in zip(ids, descriptions)}` Then dictionary `filtered` will have less number of elements than the first method.

Comment: Absolutely no repeated values, they are all unique, in `ids` and `special_ids`